# Execution of a remote Bash script fin GitHub fails

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, github

I'm trying to run a bash script on my RaspberryPi 3 model B+ with the following curl:

```
export GITHUB_TOKEN=<my_personal_access_token>

curl -sSL https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@raw.githubusercontent.com/inmarsat-enterprise/fieldedge-core/main/install.sh | bash
```

I have also tried with doing a `sudo apt install dos2unix` from another thread, but this also failed with the command:

```
curl -sSL https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@raw.githubusercontent.com/inmarsat-enterprise/fieldedge-core/main/install.sh | dos2unix |bash
```

The bash script "install.sh" contains user prompts, and it's spitting out of the script at the first one, but I have no idea how to resolve this issue?

Can anyone help?

Error I'm seeing on the Pi:

```
pi@fieldedge:~ $ curl -sSL https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@raw.githubusercontent.com/inmarsat-enterprise/fieldedge-core/main/install.sh |dos2unix | bash
[FieldEdge INFO] Starting FieldEdge setup...
[FieldEdge INFO] Using GITHUB_TOKEN for secure file access.
[FieldEdge INFO] Updating host system. This may take several minutes...
Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Continue script installation?
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1) Yes
2) No
#? #? #? #? 1) Yes
2) No
1) Yes
#? #?
pi@fieldedge:~ $
```

Comment: I believe the `fieldedge-core` repository is private and therefore we are unable to see what `install.sh` is trying to do.  You also have given almost no information about how it fails.  Is there an error?  What made you want to try dos2unix?

Comment: Hi Jesse, sorry first time using this platform. The repo is private for IPR reasons, I can share the output from the Pi? Not sure how to post that in here?

Comment: What are you typing at the prompt?  Is `1) Yes` your literal input?  It's just looking for `1` FWIW

Comment: Okay let me pull the install.sh file so you can see it. Bear with. Anyway I can upload a file into this?

Comment: None of those are errors. Do you get any other output? What makes you think there is a problem here? This is _incredibly_ unsafe as you are just blindly executing commands without checking what they do, but if you are confident the script is not dangerous, I don't see a problem here. Does it work better if you don't pipe? Try `curl -sSL https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@raw.githubusercontent.com/inmarsat-enterprise/fieldedge-core/main/install.sh > install.sh; bash ./install.sh`.

Comment: Terdon you are a genius! the curl you sent worked! Also the script is safe, it's one myself and my boss created, shouldn't be dangerous at all.

Comment: Thanks all for contributing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the issue is since there are no obvious errors, but a simple workaround is to download the script to a file and then execute that file instead of using the pipe:

```
curl -sSL https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@raw.githubusercontent.com/inmarsat-enterprise/fieldedge-core/main/install.sh > install.sh
bash ./install.sh
```